# MySQL Server Connection Socket Error

Tags: mysql, php, connection, socket

i just compiled MySQL 5.1 on SunOS 5.11 (i think xD) and now i have some problems. I am able to start the server via

`./bin/mysqld_safe &`

and i can run the *mysql** tool in /bin via Putty, however i am not able to connect to the server via PHP. Currently i am getting the following error

`Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock'`

using the simple command

`mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or die("n00b!");`

Please keep in mind, i am logged in on a system without administrative priviledges and therefore i can not edit too much system files...

Can you please help me, find out how to reconfigure the server so that it can be used via *local* php scripts and phpMyAdmin?

Greetings!

Comment: Be more clear, thinking that you're on sunOS 5.11 isn't really helping us... Also, you should get administrative priviledges to install or config anything

Comment: It **is** SunOS 5.11. Just checked it! This is the server of the university -> i am allowed to run mysql as long as it is done without these priviledges. I would use my own running xampp on Windows, however the server is much better than my local pc :D

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried connecting through TCP/IP? i.e. use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost.

Cheers

Comment: Yop. Same error. However, when i use `rayhalle2` (the hostname) the script loads and loads and loads and ... nothing.